# Create dynamic name of newly appended child

Tags: javascript

I have the following form inputs in a particular td tag.

```
<input type="text" value="" name="form_data[1][1][text]"><br>
<input type="text" value="" name="form_data[1][2][text]"><br>
<input type="text" value="" name="form_data[1][3][text]"><br>
```

Also I have the code for appending new form. But i need to change its name like this `form_data[1][4][text]` that is array name with next index for text should come.

i.e.

```
<input type="text" value="" name="form_data[1][4][text]"><br>
```

Comment: Wait, so text should have the text written in the textbox?

Comment: so if you want to change it, just do it, what's preventing you? have you tried something? if so, please share it in your question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a class to your input, get the number of elements with this class:

```
var nbElt = document.getElementsByClassName('yourclass').length;
var newInp = document.createElement('input');
newInp.name = "form_data[1]["+parseInt(nbElt+1)+"][text]";
document.body.appendChild(newImp);
```

And it's done.

Comment: Thanks, But i would like to add that new child with a particular td of table. How will i achieve this?

Comment: `particular_td.appendChild(newImp)`, where particular_td is a reference to the node which you can get in a gazillion of ways.